# Grouping bottom scores by two variables

Tags: r

I have a table that looks like this

```
uid gid score
1   a   5
1   a   8
1   a   9
1   b   2
1   b   7
2   a   5
2   a   9
.
.
.
```

But with many more entries for each user and group.

I want to get a table that has a row for each uid/gid pairing that is the mean of their bottom 5 scores.

This was trivial in Excel using pivot tables, but I need to do some analysis that R is much better for.

So I want my result to look like

```
uid gid top5avg
1   a   4.3
1   b   5.7
2   a   3.5
2   b   6.8
.
.
.
```

with one row for each uid gid pair and then the average of the top five scores for that uid/gid pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data was called dat this would work:

```
aggregate(score~uid+gid, data=dat, function(x) mean(sort(x)[1:5]))
```

**EDIT:**
If you meant the opposite (bottom 5) than what I had, as indicated by Joran (I was confused too), then use `rev` as in:

```
aggregate(score~uid+gid, data=dat, function(x) mean(rev(sort(x))[1:5]))
```

Or use the `tail` suggestion Joran made.

Answer (score 3):

This is even more trivial in R, assuming your data frame is called `dat` and you really meant bottom 5 scores (even though your example suggests the top 5):

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dat,.(uid,gid),summarise,bottom5avg = mean(tail(sort(score),5)))
```

Note that this code assumes that there will be at least 5 observations in each group.

Comment: `tail(x, 5)` when given a vector x of length <5 will return that vector exactly. So your code is robust to groups with fewer than 5 observations: when data has fewer than 5 observations in a group, the average will be done on those 1, 2, 3, or 4 observations. On the opposite, Tyler's code is less robust: it will die with such small groups. So I'd say your last sentence "this code assumes..." applies to Tyler's solution, not yours.

Answer (score 1):

And the `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
setkey(dat,uid,gid,score)
sol <- dat[,list(avg5 = mean(tail(score,5)),by='uid,gid'])
```