# Grouping by two variables and picking top values of one of them in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

I have some election data for a number of years in several states with varying number of candidates each year. An approximative reprex is below.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1124)

df <- cbind(
  sample(LETTERS[1:3], size = 40, replace = TRUE),
  as.numeric(sample(2009:2013, size = 40, replace = TRUE)), 
  sample(letters, size = 40, replace = TRUE),
  as.numeric(sample(1:5000, size = 40))
)

colnames(df) <- c("states", "year", "candidate", "votes")

df <- as.tibble(df)

df
#> # A tibble: 40 x 4
#>    states year  candidate votes
#>    <chr>  <chr> <chr>     <chr>
#>  1 B      2010  w         1402 
#>  2 A      2012  o         3646 
#>  3 A      2009  x         4073 
#>  4 A      2012  w         713  
#>  5 A      2012  n         4810 
#>  6 C      2011  i         4096 
#>  7 B      2010  u         215  
#>  8 A      2012  j         1928 
#>  9 C      2013  e         1889 
#> 10 B      2013  z         4888 
#> # ... with 30 more rows
```

I would simply like to store in a separate df the rows of the last *n* years of elections in each state. For example, the last two could be: A 2012, A 2010, B 2013, B 2010, C 2012, C 2009 and all their associated candidate and vote info (as well as others that I haven't put in the reprex as unnecessary).

I thought I could simply achieve it with something like the code below, but I'm getting everything selected... `group_by(states)` and `top_n(2, wt = year)`  does not yield the expected result, either.

I can't see any other way. Other solutions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560437/grouping-bottom-scores-by-two-variables) do not quite fit.

```r
select_df <- df %>% 
  group_by(states, year) %>% 
  top_n(n = 2, wt = year)
```

I'd be very grateful for any pointers!

Comment: If you group by states and year than the top year is always the one. Try grouping only by state and then using `top_n(2, year)`. This gives you the information you want for the last two year for each states (several rows because of duplicated year)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to avoid issues with the ties for `top_n`:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(states, year) %>%  # For clearer ordering
  group_by(states, year) %>%  
  nest() %>%                 # nest everything which is not state or year  
  group_by(states) %>%       # We want to have top years by states
  top_n(n = 2, year) %>%     # No ties and no problems with top_n
  unnest()                   # Duplicated rows for several candidates per state and year

# A tibble: 16 x 4
# Groups:   states [3]
   states year  candidate votes
   <chr>  <chr> <chr>     <chr>
 1 A      2012  o         3646 
 2 A      2012  w         713  
 3 A      2012  n         4810 
 4 A      2012  j         1928 
 5 A      2012  h         1699 
 6 A      2013  c         2873 
 7 B      2012  n         3502 
 8 B      2012  z         1079 
 9 B      2012  k         3207 
10 B      2013  z         4888 
11 B      2013  l         3483 
12 C      2012  x         2241 
13 C      2012  b         4994 
14 C      2013  e         1889 
15 C      2013  h         3858 
16 C      2013  z         186
```

Without nesting (which can get unhandy with too large datasets) you first extract the top years per state and then filter by them like the following:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(states, year) %>%   # Sorting is important to select correct years
  group_by(states) %>% 
  mutate(top_year = list(tail(unique(year), 2))) %>%  # If not pre sorted, use sort() here
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(year %in% top_year)
```

**Explanation for the first solution**
Why do we have to use `nest()`? Let's have a look, what happens if we leave it out:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(states, year) %>%  
  group_by(states, year) %>% 
  group_by(states) %>%       
  top_n(n = 2, year)         

# A tibble: 11 x 4
# Groups:   states [3]
#    states year  candidate votes
#    <chr>  <chr> <chr>     <chr>
#  1 A      2012  o         3646 
#  2 A      2012  w         713  
#  3 A      2012  n         4810 
#  4 A      2012  j         1928 
#  5 A      2012  h         1699 
#  6 A      2013  c         2873 
#  7 B      2013  z         4888 
#  8 B      2013  l         3483 
#  9 C      2013  e         1889 
# 10 C      2013  h         3858 
# 11 C      2013  z         186
```

For state A it doesn't make a difference, but for B and C. This is due to how `top_n` works. It will select the top 2 rows, weighted by the variable year.
For state A this is the year 2013 and then 2012. There are several rows with state A and the year 2012, thus `top_n` selects all of them. For State B and C the top year (2013) already fills 2 or more rows so `top_n` selects those and is done. So it does select the rows with the top year and selects years until the number of rows is filled.

Let's see what happens if we nest the data:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(states, year) %>%  
  group_by(states, year) %>%  
  nest() 

# A tibble: 14 x 3
#    states year  data            
#    <chr>  <chr> <list>          
#  1 A      2009  <tibble [3 x 2]>
#  2 A      2011  <tibble [2 x 2]>
#  3 A      2012  <tibble [5 x 2]>
#  4 A      2013  <tibble [1 x 2]>
#  5 B      2009  <tibble [2 x 2]>
#  6 B      2010  <tibble [7 x 2]>
#  7 B      2011  <tibble [1 x 2]>
#  8 B      2012  <tibble [3 x 2]>
#  9 B      2013  <tibble [2 x 2]>
# 10 C      2009  <tibble [3 x 2]>
# 11 C      2010  <tibble [2 x 2]>
# 12 C      2011  <tibble [4 x 2]>
# 13 C      2012  <tibble [2 x 2]>
# 14 C      2013  <tibble [3 x 2]>
```

Now we don't have multiple rows per year, so we really select the top 2 year with `top_n`.

Comment: thank you kath! your first solution worked like a charm! I think it's far more legible. why is nesting necessary? And why is it not handy with large datasets? (speed?)

Comment: Yes, I was referring to speed with large datasets. It depends on what you are going to do with the data - nested data can come in very handy :) 
If the answer solved your question, please accept it.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I fumbled on my phone and unclicked it! I don't quite understand why nest() is required. The documentation is really [not very enlightening](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/0.8.1/topics/nest). I'd appreciate your insights, but no worries if this requires a very long explanation. Thanks again! :)

Comment: I added some explanation for top_n and I hope it clarifies it.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend trying `slice`

```
df %>% 
  mutate(year = as.numeric(year)) %>%
  arrange(-desc(states), -desc(year)) %>%
  group_by(states) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  slice((n()-1):n())
```

[image]

Comment: Why `-desc(x)` and not just `x` within `arrange`?

Comment: kon_u, as you can see in your own example, it's "selecting by votes" (indeed, last column of df, as specified in the documentation), but I specifically would like to select by the last n years election in each state